# How to use inner join statement with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have two tables in a MySQL database:
1. Device table with some device specific values.
2. Vendor table with only a id value and name value

Now, I would like to get two values, model name and the vendor_id, from the device table. But instead to show the vendor_id I would like to display the corresponding vendor name.
So in the MySQL Workbench this statement is working fine and shows me the expected result like Model = N95 and Vendor = Nokia

```
SELECT device.model, vendor.vendor from device inner join vendor on device.vendor_id = vendor.id
```

Now I'm using Hibernate to get the values from tables.

```
public List<Device> listDevices() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "SELECT device.model, vendor.vendor from device inner join vendor on device.vendor_id = vendor.id";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(Device.class);
        List list = query.list();
        allDevices = new ArrayList();
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            device = (Device) iterator.next();
            allDevices.add(device);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        return allDevices;
    }
}
```

But this is not working I got this exception:

```
SEVERE:   Column 'id' not found.
SEVERE:   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
at com.vodafone.omisuite.model.DeviceData.listDevices(DeviceData.java:154)
at com.vodafone.omisuite.model.DeviceData.<init>(DeviceData.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1811)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:869)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1133)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2851)
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:28)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1097)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:565)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
... 76 more
```

If I use the following statement instead its working, but it shows me the ID values for the vendor_id and not the corresponding names.

```
SELECT * from device inner join vendor on device.vendor_id = vendor.id
```

For both tables I have created java classes and two *.hbm.xml files. In the hibernate.cfg.xml file both mappings are configured.

Can anyone help and explain me what I did wrong and how can I fix this?
If you have an advice how to create a corresponding HQL statement please feel free to post ;-)

This is the device class created through Hibernate!

```
/**
* Device generated by hbm2java
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="device"
,catalog="myDB"
)
public class Device  implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String version;
private String shortname;
private int vendorId;
private String model;
private String platform;
private String appIconSize;
private String description;
private String uaProfile;
private byte[] image;
private String imageMimetype;
private int internetonly;
private int creator;
private int approvable;
private int approved;
private Date changed;

public Device() {
}


public Device(String shortname, int vendorId, String model, String platform, int  internetonly, int creator, int approvable, int approved, Date changed) {
    this.shortname = shortname;
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
    this.model = model;
    this.platform = platform;
    this.internetonly = internetonly;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.approvable = approvable;
    this.approved = approved;
    this.changed = changed;
}
public Device(String shortname, int vendorId, String model, String platform, String    appIconSize, String description, String uaProfile, byte[] image, String imageMimetype,  int  internetonly, int creator, int approvable, int approved, Date changed) {
   this.shortname = shortname;
   this.vendorId = vendorId;
   this.model = model;
   this.platform = platform;
   this.appIconSize = appIconSize;
   this.description = description;
   this.uaProfile = uaProfile;
   this.image = image;
   this.imageMimetype = imageMimetype;
   this.internetonly = internetonly;
   this.creator = creator;
   this.approvable = approvable;
   this.approved = approved;
   this.changed = changed;
}

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="version")
public String getVersion() {
    return this.version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Column(name="shortname", nullable=false)
public String getShortname() {
    return this.shortname;
}

public void setShortname(String shortname) {
    this.shortname = shortname;
}

@Column(name="vendor_id", nullable=false)
public int getVendorId() {
    return this.vendorId;
}

public void setVendorId(int vendorId) {
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
}

@Column(name="model", nullable=false)
public String getModel() {
    return this.model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

@Column(name="platform", nullable=false, length=7)
public String getPlatform() {
    return this.platform;
}

public void setPlatform(String platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
}

@Column(name="app_icon_size", length=10)
public String getAppIconSize() {
    return this.appIconSize;
}

public void setAppIconSize(String appIconSize) {
    this.appIconSize = appIconSize;
}

@Column(name="description")
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name="ua_profile")
public String getUaProfile() {
    return this.uaProfile;
}

public void setUaProfile(String uaProfile) {
    this.uaProfile = uaProfile;
}

@Column(name="image")
public byte[] getImage() {
    return this.image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Column(name="image_mimetype", length=16)
public String getImageMimetype() {
    return this.imageMimetype;
}

public void setImageMimetype(String imageMimetype) {
    this.imageMimetype = imageMimetype;
}

@Column(name="internetonly", nullable=false)
public int getInternetonly() {
    return this.internetonly;
}

public void setInternetonly(int internetonly) {
    this.internetonly = internetonly;
}

@Column(name="creator", nullable=false)
public int getCreator() {
    return this.creator;
}

public void setCreator(int creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
}

@Column(name="approvable", nullable=false)
public int getApprovable() {
    return this.approvable;
}

public void setApprovable(int approvable) {
    this.approvable = approvable;
}

@Column(name="approved", nullable=false)
public int getApproved() {
    return this.approved;
}

public void setApproved(int approved) {
    this.approved = approved;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="changed", nullable=false, length=19)
public Date getChanged() {
    return this.changed;
}

public void setChanged(Date changed) {
    this.changed = changed;
}

}
```

Comment: You are us sing hibernate, use HQL. This will be super simple. The H docs are good on these matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to return the list of devices. This is not plain SQL and here you work with associations. By default ManyToOne associations (your case) are eager and you'll be able to get it without additional efforts, i.e. device.getVendor().getVendor().

If you want to return only 2 strings you can return map:

```
select new map (device.model as model, vendor.vendor as vendor) from Model model, Vendor vendor where device.vendor = vendor
```

**edit:**

Also you have to create the association. For this remove vendorId property and alter your code like this:

```
public class Device implements java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    private Vendor vendor;
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", nullable=false)
    public int getVendorId() {
        return this.vendorId;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I tried it with your the statement you posted but I got an Error in MySQL Workbench that I have a error in the SQL syntax. Same meesage in the GlassFish output Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: The exact error in MySQL Workbench is this: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(device.model as model, vendor.vendor as vendor) from Model model, Vendor vendor' at line 1

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.0 and MySQL Community Edition 5.6.13.1

Comment: I see. This is an HQL statement, not SQL.

Comment: If I execute the HQL statement you provided in NetBeans. On hibernate.cfg.xml right click and "RUN HQL Query" then I got this Exception: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Model is not mapped [select new map (device.model as model, vendor.vendor as vendor) from Model model, com.vodafone.omisuite.bean.Vendor vendor where device.vendor = vendor]    I can not copy the full stacktrace to the comment section because it is too long.

Comment: Btw: I didn't understand the "Model model" in your HQL statement. I have no model table I think this should be Device device ?

Comment: Can you show Device class then? Does it have ManyToOne relation?

Comment: True, my fault, sorry. It should be "Device device" instead of "Model model"

Comment: I have added the Device class definition. I have no ManyToOne relation.

Comment: OK this HQL solves my problem: "select device.model, vendor.vendor from Device device, Vendor vendor where device.vendorId = vendor.id"    thanks a lot for your patience!!!

Comment: Well I think I was too fast with the conclusion. So from the NetBeansIDE "Run HQL Query" window it works I get the correct result. But in my code I'm not sure how to get the values from List list = query.list();. Because as I did in my example above is not working anymore because now I get two objects from query.list()...do you have any advice ?

Comment: This is list of Map objects so the java code is: for (Map entry: result) { String currentModel = (String)entry.get("model"); String currentVendor = (String)entry.get("vendor"); }

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve entities of type Device, and although you didn't mention it but I guess that Device is a persistent class and it has a column named **id** which is annotated as being the hibernate @Id. Thus I guess hibernate will try to create new Device objects but it needs desperately the Device id since it is the primary key but it is not finding it in the select list. But this is not what you really want what you want is only the device model and the vendor and not the Device object!

To solve your problem you have to:

1. remove query.addEntity(Device.class);
2. use something called constructor queries something like select new YourSimplePOJO(device.model, vendor.vendor) of course your POJO class **YourSimplePOJO** should have a constructor that has two parameters.

Comment: Yes the device class is mapped in the Device.hbm.xml file to the device table. The device class has all the attributes from the device table and the id is PK.